# Why do bounties expire?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Why do bounties expire? I don't know if there is an answer to this question, but I wonder why bounties can't be available until they get an answer instead of a limited amount of time.

Answer (score 19):

If bounties didn't expire, then the bounty board would eventually fill up with unanswered questions. New questions with bounties placed on them wouldn't be visible, so the whole bounty system would lose any effectiveness that it has.

The way the system works now, placing a bounty is more like paying to advertise your question. You're not guaranteed an answer, just a more prominent spot where people will see it for some time. That encourages people to make sure they've explored other avenues and taken the time to make their question as clear and concise as they can before spending their reputation on it.

Comment: You should probably include in your answer that the bountied questions are in order of oldest first ‍‍.